# Facebook API email missing, invalid or hasn't been confirmed. Despite having all permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

several customers can't login to my website with facebook API, because email is required and Facebook is not providing it. Then I decided to mess up with my own facebook account. I deleted my email address. Then added same address again. I received confirmation email from FB, then I confirmed my email. But now I have the same issue.

when I call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cemail%2Cbirthday&debug=true&access_token=EAAY***
```

Response from FB is

```
  {
    "id": "101***",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "birthday": "01/01/1990",
    "__debug__": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "message": "The email field was not returned. This may be because the email was\n      missing, invalid or hasn't been confirmed.",
          "type": "info"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

No email is returned.
Permissions are granted
If I call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/permissions?debug=true&access_token=EAAY***
```

Response from FB is

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "permission": "user_birthday",
        "status": "granted"
      },
      {
        "permission": "email",
        "status": "granted"
      },
      {
        "permission": "public_profile",
        "status": "granted"
      }
    ],
    "__debug__": {}
  }
```

There is a screenshot from my FB profile contacts. I have email address.

[image]

Error message from 1st request says "email was missing, invalid or hasn't been confirmed."
What should be done to get the email from Facebook? What should be done with my account?

Comment: First of all, try and remove the app from https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications - and then log in again, and see if anything changed.

Comment: @CBroe I've tried it already. As I mentioned before. I've received FB access_token, but FB not providing email, but permission to view email was granted. I can view granted permission via API, and I see it in UI

Comment: You said you deleted your email and added a new one, that is not the same thing as I suggested. (Might be that you already tried that as well - but that is not what you said, so no reason to give me lip here.)